# Responsive Dapp Patterns

Tags: solidity, dapp-development

I would like to develop Dapp which aimed to be very responsive. I mean users should not wait until some small operations will be added to the block.
Is this next pattern correct for Dapp? 
*I'm going to immediate handle user's activity in browser JS code and change UI state regarding user activity.*
As I undestand correct my transaction will be added to the ethereum blockchain anyway so I'm not forced to wait until this will happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a responsive user interface and there are many ways to approach it.

Transactions are submitted and you get callbacks with the transaction hashes. You can then consider the transaction pending, but you should probably not proceed on the assumption that success is assured. That might lead to a confusing and misleading user interface.

I've found success with CSS and Javascript. Consider a table edit UI where every row is a record and every column is a field. This user moves around at will, like a spreadsheet. You could listen for blur events and submit something when the cursor moves off a field or off a record. That does something to submit a transaction and visually signal a processing/pending status; maybe a spinner, maybe the field turns yellow.

If the contract is well-designed, there ought to be a corresponding event when a state-change happens. That's the confirmation. The heard state-change should be expected (or it possibly came from another user). Either way, update the UI. Remove/reset the pending/processing visual indicator because this data is "official". You could even visually change "pending" to "failed" in the case that an expected confirmation is long overdue.

If you do something similar, users should be able to roam around quickly leaving trails of pending updates behind them, and they should be swept up as the confirmations arrive.

Hope it helps.